# Add-PnPPageWebPart: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to add QuickLinks to my SharePoint site using the pnp Module. However, when trying to run the comand:
Add-PnPPageWebPart -Page $page -DefaultWebPartType "QuickLinks" -Section 2 -Column 1
I get the error: Add-PnPPageWebPart: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I tried multiple things, I even get the error when trying to run the examples from: https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Add-PnPPageWebPart.html

I tried creating the section manually and running examples

Answer (score 0):

The error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" in PowerShell, specifically when using PnP PowerShell, usually occurs when you try to access or modify a property or method on an object that is currently null or not initialized. In the context of Add-PnPPageWebPart, this error might occur if there is an issue with the provided parameters.